# How can i design table view cell as per my requirement

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am developed one app in phonegap and sencha.
 In that i wrote a css for div to fit as per the text. 
But in native application if text increases then the label cannot display the full text it displayed some text and dots.
 I want to display the full text. I don't know how it can be possible. If it is possible then please suggest me.

Comment: so you want to know that how to remove that dots in native application , right ?

Comment: See http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/ this tutorial for the implementation. See https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1ASAA_enIN430IN430&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&rlz=1C1ASAA_enIN430IN430&q=ios+resize+uitableviewcell+row+height+according+to+text+length&sa=X&ei=aKiCUe3zMdCGrAfZn4CACg&ved=0CCwQ7xYoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e8cb228a72cb543b&ion=1&biw=1280&bih=675">this</a> for more results.

Comment: @Jean-LucGodard i want to display the full text

Comment: you can take a UILable to display that text in tableviewcell and set the UILable's height as per it's content and then you can set cell size as per lable's contentsize.

Comment: @RamsChowdary ,,, in native iOS or Sencha/Phonegap ?

Comment: @Jean-LucGodard in native ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is first get the Height of text based upon font and size then return the height of UITableViewCell for each cell.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NSString *aMessage;

if ([self.messageArray count] >0) {
    aMessage = [self.messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(270, 9999);
UIFont *textFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:MessageFontSize];
CGSize myStringSize = [aMessage sizeWithFont:textFont
                       constrainedToSize:maximumSize
                           lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

return myStringSize.height+10 //to have some extra space b/w cells +10;   
}
```

An then add a Custom label in UITableViewCell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"LazyTableCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil){
  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}    

NSString *aMessage;

if ([self.messageArray count] >0) {
    aMessage = [self.messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

UILabel *messageTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 270, 0)];
messageTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
messageTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
messageTextLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
messageTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:MessageFontSize];
messageTextLabel.text = aMessage;
[messageTextLabel sizeToFit];
[cell addSubview:messageTextLabel];

cell.selectionStyle= UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate class of type `UITableViewCell` lets say `MyTableCell`

then design the cell in that `MyTableCell` class as per your need.

Now you can use the object of `MyTableCell` in `datasource` method of `tableView` where you are actually putting the table

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyTableCell *cell = [MyTableCell alloc]init];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    // Processing

    return cell;

}
```

**Hope this will help you**